What is the range of expectation value in quantum machine learning
If I want to build a quantum circuit to solve a regression problem in machine learning, and the target value is 200~300. In qiskit, we can use VQR to easily implement it, and it will output the expectation value as the prediction, but I found the expectation value is usually around -1 ~ 1, which is far away from the targeted value. How can we understand this issue? Or can we say quantum circuit is not a good choice for regression in machine learning? And I tried to normalize the y_value before training, and observed a better performance, in this case, can we say that in terms of regression, we have to scale the y_value into the expectation value range for good performance?
And I noticed the training of this quantum circuit took much longer time than classical machine learning,like xgboost, simple neural network, is it normal? My understanding is that each data point in the training dataset has to be passed into the circuit one by one, and this is why it takes so long time. If this is true, it seems like quantum machine learning is not a good choice for large dataset. At least in classical neural network, we can feed batch data into the model and do the training in parallel, but in quantum circuit, it seems impossible. If it is correct, then how can we show the efficiency of quantum machine learning?
def create_qnn(n_qubits: int = 4):
    feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(n_qubits, reps=2)
    ansatz = EfficientSU2(n_qubits, reps=1)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)
    qc.compose(feature_map, inplace=True)
    qc.compose(ansatz, inplace=True)

    qnn = EstimatorQNN(
        circuit=qc,
        input_params=feature_map.parameters,
        weight_params=ansatz.parameters,
        input_gradients=True)
    return qnn

qnn4 = create_qnn()
regressor = NeuralNetworkRegressor(
    neural_network=qnn4,
    loss="squared_error",
    optimizer=COBYLA(maxiter=200),
    callback=callback_graph)
#x_train.shape is [1000,4]
#y_train.shape is [1000,]
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

